# How to use systemGrayXColor in InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In the [Apple documentation under Adaptable Gray Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors?language=objc) I can read that they provide, among other colors:

- systemGray2Color
- systemGray3Color
- systemGray4Color
- systemGray5Color
- systemGray6Color

In the Interface Builder of Xcode (Version 11.2.1) I can see **systemGrayColor** but non of the other shades of gray:

[image]

How do I set those other system gray colors in the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I could use the color by manually changing it in the underlaying XML.

I changed the `systemColor` attribute of the `color` XML element.

1. In the Interface Builder set the Background color to `System Gray Color`
2. In the Xcode right click on the Storyboard/Xib file and use `Open as` -> `Source Code` entry
3. Search the View you want to change and within that view the `color` XML element
4. Change the `systemColor="systemGrayColor"` to `systemColor="systemGray2Color"` for color system gray 2.
5. Use step 2 and open the Storyboard/Xib file in the Interface Builder again and Save the file so the `red`, `green` and `blue` color attributes of the same XML key also gets adjusted.

Resulting in:

[image]

As mentiond in the question already there are the following shades of gray supported:

- systemGray2Color
- systemGray3Color
- systemGray4Color
- systemGray5Color
- systemGray6Color

My tests revealed if you misspell the color or use a not supported shade the Interface Builder will show black color instead.

This was done using Xcode Version 11.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Xcode and will be fixed in the [upcoming Xcode 11.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_release_notes/):

> Added dynamic system gray colors to inspector color pickers. (55403376) (FB7281404)

Comment: Thanks very much. Do we have some list on what bugs Apple currently works on?

Comment: @BrunoBieri, you can look into Known Issues sections in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_beta_2_release_notes

Comment: Thanks for the hint, as you mentioned it in the answer too. I would be interested what other issues are open that Apple works on. Does Apple let the developer community know about it? I know it from Microsoft Visual Studio Developer Community (developercommunity.visualstudio.com) and I'm wondering if Apple does the same?